# Unity isn't allowed to use location - Windows 10

Tags: unity-game-engine, location, windows-10, location-services

I am using location services in a Unity 3D game. I am using this (slightly modified) script that I found in the Unity Documentation just for testing purposes. Here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestLocationService : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            print("no");
            yield break;

            // Start service before querying location
            Input.location.Start();

            // Wait until service initializes
            int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing     && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        print("Timed out");
        yield break;
    }

    // Connection has failed
    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        print("Unable to determine device location");
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
        print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
    }

    // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
    Input.location.Stop();
}
```

}

When I run the script, it is supposed to print my location. However, it thinks that location services are not enabled (I am using Windows 10) and just prints "no" before stopping. In my location settings, I have location enabled.

[image]

Why isn't Unity allowed to use my location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location access in Unity is for Handheld Devices Only(i.e. Mobiles and Tablets). You cannot use it on a Computer.

Unity Docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-location.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to give Unity the permission to use the location services also.
If you scroll down on the screenshot that you posted, you will have to toggle the switch for Unity also.

If that doesn't work you might want to try installing some sort of geo sensor and see if it makes any difference.

Based on http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1219218/windows-10-using-location-with-unity-through-pc-no.html the api **Input.location.isEnabledByUser** is supposed to work only for **(handheld devices only)**

Comment: There isn't a toggle switch for Unity. Is there some setting I need to enable within Unity?

Comment: you can try http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/drivers-hardware/50767d1438836176t-find-my-device-wifi-feature-set-up-page-says-off-28806d1438836176-location-service-turn-off-windows-10-location_on_for_device-1.png